# Clarifying a simple list of data changes

Tags: lists, desktop-application, data

On the left side I have a list of (currently) 3 items. These items have their own list of changes on the right. See screenshot:

[image]

This represents "new data --> [position]". The application gets a file that contains the data and directly sends it to a machine. The data is an instruction, and what the previous data is/was doesn't matter for the user. So there is no concept of going up or down or adding/subtracting.

This application is normally minimized, but if someone wants to see what happened they need to be able to understand this without having to read a lot or ask me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I don't know what information could be missing. It isn't more detailed than what I explained.

Comment: Try to add more context to the question about the actual usage. Like what are users going to do with this, what is the problem it needs to solve? Why is the current design not clear and what do you mean with "...what happened to that position...", what could have happened and why? There is so little context that it is impossible to give an answer that will actually solve your problem.

Comment: @jazZRo With "what happened to that position" I mean the fact that we write new data to it. I want the user to see that. Users are actually not going to do anything with this application normally. It will be minimized out of view, but we need the option of opening the application and seeing that something happened. I just want it to be clear what the right list represents so they don't have to call me and ask.

Comment: This is quite common in sports or any website that includes some ranking, including this one. Just click on your profile and check your ranking and you'll see all UX.SE users with their previous position depending on the time range (yearly, monthly, weekly). Simply put: it's more or less what you have, just remove the arrow, it adds too much noise and cognitive load. The current position and the previous position within parentheses should be ok. You could even add color, like red for a lower position and green for a higher position.

Comment: @Devin I guess I just realized there is a bit of context I failed to add: the numbers hold no importance relative to each other. There is no concept of going up or down, adding or subtracting. Putting 4 where the value was previously 1 does not mean the number went up.

Comment: well, then don't use color, simply inform the previous position and that's it